# Почему в начале цикла параметр i равен двум

Tags: pascal, for

Помогите разобраться в элементарной задаче. Пользователем вводится диапазон чисел, которые затем рандомно генерируются и выводятся в порядке возрастания.

Мой ответ "потому что при сортировке проверяется предыдущий элемент массива" не приняли

```
for i := 2 to n do
    for j := n downto i do
      if A[j] < A[j - 1] then
      begin
        tmp := A[j - 1];
        A[j - 1] := A[j];
        A[j] := tmp;
 end;
```

Comment: `i := 2` - наводит на размышления

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно преподавателю не понравилось, что вы пишете цикл от 2 а не от 1. Обычно сортировку пузырьком делают так.

```
for i := 1 to n-1 do
    for j := 1 to n-i do
      if A[j] > A[j + 1] then
      begin
        tmp := A[j + 1];
        A[j] := A[j + 1];
        A[j + 1] := tmp;
      end;
```

Хотя по мне можно и от 2. Они по сути идентичны.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно, если по возрастанию, пишу так:

```
for i := 1 to n-1 do
  for j := i+1 to n do
    if A[j] > A[i] then begin
      tmp := A[j];
      A[j] := A[i];
      A[i] := tmp;
    end;
```

Если по убыванию, то знак > меняю на <.